# Consuming a webservice with <wsdl:import> over SSL redirection

Tags: java, web-services, redirect, ssl, cxf

I've deployed a contract-first web service using CXF.

The server into which it is deployed performs 302 redirections from http to ssl, so any request to http://server/app/* returns an HTTP 302 error code and redirects to https://server/app/*.

In the original WSDL there are references to XSD elements in another namespace, so the generated WSDL (the one http://server/app/services/MyService?wsdl provides) contains a `<wsdl:import>` element.

If I try to invoke the WS by manually building a SOAP request in a String and send it over an SSL socket, the WS responds correctly. I've got all necessary certificates in my keystore.

However, when I try to build a client using CXF's wsdl2java pointing to `https://server/app/services/MyService?wsdl`, I get the following error (complete stack trace below):

```
[Fatal Error] MyService?wsdl=MyServicePortType.wsdl:1:50: 
    White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.
```

The trace is referring to the `<wsdl:import>` statement. Its `location` attribute is `http://server:80/app/services/MyService?wsdl=MyServicePortType.wsdl`. My guess is that the error is thrown because of the 302 redirection. It should be `https://server/app/services/MyService?wsdl=MyServicePortType.wsdl` instead.

The original WSDL is URL-agnostic, and the service's URL is defined relative in a Spring `<jaxws:endpoint>` element. It is accessed through the CXF servlet. That is, there's no `<soap:address>` element in the original WSDL's `<wsdl:port>`.

```
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml"/>
<bean id="myServiceBean" class="mypackage.MyServiceImpl" />
<jaxws:endpoint 
    id="myServiceEndpoint" 
    implementor="#myServiceBean" 
    address="/MyService">
</jaxws:endpoint>
```

Should I specify somewhere in the service's autogenerated classes, WSDL or Spring configuration that the service is to be deployed on SSL? And how could I do it?

**EDIT**: 
Possibly related link:

- [jax-ws doesn't like http redirect?](http://markmail.org/message/q4ymfk4uw7lgzdhp#query%3a+page:1+mid%3aukm2y62gjpbdvqxm+state%3aresults) discussion on markmail.

Complete stacktrace:

```
D:\>wsdl2java -d src -client -impl -verbose -db xmlbeans -autoNameResolution -validate -compile -classdir classes https://server/app/services/MyService?wsdl
Loading FrontEnd jaxws ...
Loading DataBinding xmlbeans ...
wsdl2java -d src -client -impl -verbose -db xmlbeans -autoNameResolution -valida
te -compile -classdir classes https://server/app/services/MyService?wsdl
wsdl2java - Apache CXF 2.3.2

[Fatal Error] MyService?wsdl=MyServicePortType.wsdl:1:50: White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.

WSDLToJava Error: org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLRuntimeException: Fail to create wsdl definition from : https://server/app/services/MyService?wsdl
Caused by : WSDLException (at /wsdl:definitions/wsdl:import): faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'http://server:80/app/services/MyService?wsdl=MyServicePortType.wsdl'.: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.

org.apache.cxf.tools.common.ToolException: org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLRuntimeException: Fail to create wsdl definition from : https://server/app/services/MyService?wsdl
Caused by : WSDLException (at /wsdl:definitions/wsdl:import): faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'http://server:80/app/services/MyService?wsdl=MyServicePortType.wsdl'.: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:288)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:103)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:113)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:86)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.main(WSDLToJava.java:184)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLRuntimeException: Fail to create wsdl definition from : https://server/app/services/MyService?wsdl
Caused by : WSDLException (at /wsdl:definitions/wsdl:import): faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'http://server:80/app/services/MyService?wsdl=MyServicePortType.wsdl'.: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.
        at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLDefinitionBuilder.parseWSDL(WSDLDefinitionBuilder.java:97)
        at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLDefinitionBuilder.build(WSDLDefinitionBuilder.java:69)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.wsdl11.JAXWSDefinitionBuilder.build(JAXWSDefinitionBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.wsdl11.JAXWSDefinitionBuilder.build(JAXWSDefinitionBuilder.java:61)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.processWsdl(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:170)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:137)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:280)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException (at /wsdl:definitions/wsdl:import): faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'http://server:80/app/services/MyService?wsdl=MyServicePortType.wsdl'.: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.
        at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseImport(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseDefinitions(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:237)
        at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.getDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:186)
        at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLDefinitionBuilder.parseWSDL(WSDLDefinitionBuilder.java:78)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseExceptionpublicId: http://server:80/app/services/MyService?wsdl=MyServicePortType.wsdl; systemId: http://server:80/app/services/MyService?wsdl=MyServicePortType.wsdl; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 50; White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
        ... 18 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the service implementation `mypackage.MyServiceImpl` was missing the [`javax.jws.WebService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/jws/WebService.html) annotation.

Once included with the proper `serviceName`, `portName`, `targetNamespace`, and `endpointInterface` attributes, the service deployed without `<wsdl:import>`. I suspect this has to do mainly with the `targetNamespace` attribute.

However, external XSD's still get referenced with http addresses, like `<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://server:80/app/schema/myschema.xsd">`. I referenced them relative in the original WSDL. The only solution to this for me has been inlining all XSD definitions in the original WSDL.